# Leer ruta con caracter unicode en python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Tengo que utilizar python 2.7 para leer una ruta que tiene un caracter unicode y una Ñ, y no entiendo muy bien cómo conseguirlo.

Cuando copio y pego en vscode he podido ver que hay un caracter U+200E que me está dando problemas, algo así es lo que me aparece:

```
ruta = C:/Principio de la ruta[U+200E]‎ - palabra con Ñ/Carpeta
```

La ruta es un enlace a una carpeta de One Drive a la que no puedo cambiarle el nombre.

Cuando he probado a leer desde python 3 con la ruta así:

```
ruta = f'C:/Principio de la ruta‎{u"\u200E"} - palabra con Ñ/Carpeta'
print(os.path.exists(ruta))
>>> True
```

Si que consigo que me reconozca la ruta, pero estoy obligado a hacerlo con python 2.7 y aunque he hecho pruebas poniendo `ruta = u'.....'`, no consigo que me reconozca la ruta (con `print(os.path.exists(ruta))` me devuelve `False`), ya que no entiendo muy bien como funciona el `encode` y el `decode`. Y al intentar imprimirla (`print(ruta)`) me devuelve:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 45: character maps to <undefined>
```

¿Cómo tendría que asignar la ruta a una variable para poder leerla sin problemas?

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya lo he conseguido, he tenido que poner `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` al principio del código

y la ruta ponerla como:

```
ruta = u'C:/Principio de la ruta‎\u200E - palabra con \u00D1/Carpeta'
```

Comment: De hecho, es posible que en el código de error mencione al [PEP 263](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/), donde se indica cómo manejar estos caracteres.